# Can I use my Mac as a proxy for Ubuntu?

Tags: mac, network, unix, proxy

I have an Ubuntu PC (IP: 132.195.2.2) set up which should be connecting through a switch to my iMac (IP: 132.195.2.1) in order to gain internet access. The iMac has "share internet connection" turned on. I've added the iMac's IP in the gateway, DNS and search domain field in the configuration for the eth0 on the Ubuntu PC. I also added the iMac's IP as proxy for all services. They can ping each other PC/Mac, but the only thing my Ubuntu PC gets when calling any URL is my addressbook server web admin page.

Any idea what I've done wrong or how to set this up the right way?

Comment: How does the mac get an internet connection, same ethernet port?

Comment: no the mac gets it from it's airport and shares it to the ethernet connection

Comment: Did some other article tell you to change the dns, gateway, search domain, proxy etc? What if all that were default, as when the mac is sharing it is supposed to have a rudimentary dhcp server and forward dns requests properly.

Answer (score 1):

The mac firewall must be disabled for this to work.

You can follow [this guide if needed for NAT setup on the mac and verification of ubuntu settings](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-configure-macosx-as-nat-router/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Ubuntu PC is not getting correct DNS information.

On the Ubuntu PC, remove any settings you may have added for the iMac. Let it grab all the details automatically from the iMac.

It should just work(tm).

It won't work properly if network settings are changed on the client machine as the sharing system sends client machines all the correct IP and DNS details.

Comment: How can that work without a dhcp server on any of the ethernet connections? Does the iMac automaticly act as dhcp server when it's set to share it's connection?

Comment: Yes it sure does!

Comment: ok cool. I'll try this

Comment: Well I just changed everything on the Ubuntu machine back to blank and dhcp. It doesn't work. I can ping the iMac but nothing else answers me.